# C++ container — variable byte coded numbers list

Tags: c++, iterator, collections, bitwise, vectors

I'm writing a container for unsigned integers, which uses variable byte coding. It works but some decisions I took look ugly so I would be glad if you gave me some hints for improving the design.

**I have some specific places to get comments about**:

1. taking and storing reference in VBOutputIterator constructor
2. should I DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN in VBOutputIterator
3. == operator in VBInputIterator
4. using of malloc, realloc and free in VBList (couldn't come up with a std::vector solution)

But general advice is welcome as well)

Also, recently came across a job ad where they required to "be able to write robust and maintainable code". **How do you think, is my code robust or maintainable?** How can I make it more so?

**VBInputIterator.h**

```
template <class ForwardIterator_t, class num_t=unsigned>
class VBInputIterator
    {
    public:
    typedef num_t value_type;
    typedef num_t& reference;
    typedef num_t* pointer;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    // default gives the end
    // see operator==
    VBInputIterator()
        : _end(true)
        {
        }
    VBInputIterator(VBInputIterator const & other) = default;
    VBInputIterator & operator=(VBInputIterator &) = default;

    explicit
    VBInputIterator(ForwardIterator_t const & arr)
        : _in (arr)
        , _end(false)
        {
        ++*this;
        }
    ~VBInputIterator()
        {
        }

//    void swap(VBInputIterator& other) noexcept {
//        using std::swap;
//        swap(_in, other._in);
//    }

    VBInputIterator&
    operator++ ()
        {
        _n = 0;
        // if the first char == 128, it's the end of the stream
        if (static_cast<unsigned char>(*_in) == 0x80)
            {
            _end = true;
            return *this;
            }

        // while char < 128

        // lol
        // you can choose any variant
        // or even leave both))
        while ((*_in & 0x80) != 0x80)
        while (*_in & 0x80 ^ 0x80)
            {
            _n |= *_in;
            _n <<= 7;
            ++_in;
            }
        _n |= *_in & 0x7F;
        ++_in;

        return *this;
        }

    VBInputIterator
    operator++ (int)
        {
        VBInputIterator r (*this);
        ++*this;
        return r;
        }

    // This part is what I would like to hear some suggestions about.
    //
    // to allow constructions such as while (iter != end)
    // I implemented operator==. But how do I construct
    // end iterator on default constructor, if I'm not
    // even given the iterator (in default constructor that is)
    // So I decided to keep a private boolean _end,
    // and assign it to true when I meet the termination character.
    // in ==, I just return _end.
    // this allows some great constructions such as
    // (iter != iter) that work perfectly fine.
    //
    // maybe I should have some static instance of that iterator
    // denoting the end and return it every time, and then
    // if I'm comparing with that end iter I just return _end
    // and if not, I would compare underlying _in iterators or something
    bool
    operator== (VBInputIterator const & other) const
        {
        return _end;
        }

    bool
    operator!= (VBInputIterator const & other) const
        {
        return ! (*this == other);
        }

    num_t const
    operator* () const
        {
        return _n;
        }

    private:
    num_t _n; // current number iterator points to
    ForwardIterator_t _in;
    bool _end; // see operator==
    };
```

**VBOutputIterator.h**

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
TypeName(TypeName&) = delete;              \
void operator=(TypeName) = delete;

// bool terminating template argument:
// if true, we terminate the stream after each written number
// (and at the very beginning, in the constructor) and then
// overwrite the terminating character when writing a new number.
// can be set to false if OutputIterator_t doesn't support overwriting
// same elements.
// I put it in template parameters because then in the generated bytecode
// there is no checking, it's as if i used #ifdef or something.
// moreover, if you create a VBOutputIterator for some iterator,
// the iterator either supports overwriting or doesn't, so this boolean
// is a one-time decision, totally ok to hold it in template parameters.
// looks ugly though.
template <class OutputIterator_t, class num_t=unsigned, bool terminating=true>
class VBOutputIterator
    {
    public:
    typedef num_t value_type;
    typedef num_t& reference;
    typedef num_t* pointer;
    typedef std::output_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    // note that I'm taking &out as a parameter, and _out is & as well
    // this is done so that I can take, for example, ostreambuf_iterator
    // which is noncopyable. But I don't really like the solution
    explicit
    VBOutputIterator(OutputIterator_t & out)
        : _out(out)
        {
        // so far there are no elements, so terminate the "stream"
        if (terminating) terminate();
        }

    VBOutputIterator&
    operator=(num_t n)
        {
        if (n == 0) throw std::invalid_argument("we don't store zeros here");

        // "you are not expected to understand this"
        char _arr_buf[sizeof(num_t)*8/7 + 1];
        char* i = _arr_buf;
        do  {
            *i = n & 0x7F;
            ++i;
            n >>= 7;
            } while (n > 0);
        // now i points to the one past end character of our sequence

        _arr_buf[0] |= 0x80;

        // write bytes in reverse order to the out stream
        while (i != _arr_buf)
            {
            --i;
            *_out = *i;
            ++_out;
            }

        if (terminating) terminate();

        return *this;
        }

    // my stream of bytes is terminated by 0x80 character
    // , it's like null-terminated string
    inline
    void
    terminate()
        {
        *_out = 0x80;
        }

    // these are no-op, as they are in ostreambuf_iterator
    // hey, and how can make them a no-op?
    // I don't know how long the next number would be,
    // so I can't reserve space for them, so I can't
    // increment iterator without writing a number.
    VBOutputIterator&
    operator*()
        {
        return *this;
        }
    VBOutputIterator&
    operator++()
        {
        return *this;
        }
    VBOutputIterator&
    operator++(int)
        {
        return *this;
        }

    private:
    // most such restrictions are due to
    // ostreambuf_iterator and alike iterators
    // that can't be copied. But maybe I should
    // that class so that it works with char arrays
    // (which can be copied, where you can overwrite
    // one location several times) and then if
    // my class client wants to pass ostreambuf_iterator
    // and decides to take a copy, it won't compile or
    // maybe some bug will be introduced, but that's
    // just his problem.
    //
    // so what should I do: restrict or let the user decide?
    DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(VBOutputIterator);

    // this is where the output goes
    OutputIterator_t & _out;
    };
```

**VBList.h**

```
#include "VBInputIterator.h"
#include "VBOutputIterator.h"

template <typename num_t>
class VBList
    {
    public:
    typedef VBInputIterator<char*> iterator;
    VBList()
        : VBList(max_vb_size)
        {
        }
    VBList(size_t capacity)
        : _size(0)
        , _capacity(capacity)
        , _arr_start(static_cast<char*>(malloc(_capacity)))
        , _arr_iter(_arr_start)
        , _output(_arr_iter)
        {
        ensure_capacity();
        }
    ~VBList()
        {
        free(_arr_start);
        }
    void
    push_back(num_t n)
        {
        ensure_capacity();
        _output = n;
        ++_size;
        }

    iterator
    begin()
        {
        return iterator(_arr_start);
        }
    iterator
    end()
        {
        return iterator();
        }

    private:
    static size_t const max_vb_size = sizeof(num_t)*8/7 + 1;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;
    char * _arr_start;
    char * _arr_iter;
    VBOutputIterator<char*, num_t> _output;

    // =====================
    // note how I store char* _arr_iter,
    // I initialize VBOutputIterator with it,
    // but VBOutputIterator takes a reference, not a copy.
    // so it changes where _arr_iter points to.
    // when I ensure_capacity, I create a new array (realloc)
    // and assign _arr_iter to a new value,
    // and VBOutputIterator starts writing to a new place
    // because it holds a reference to _arr_iter!
    // looks creepy but I couldn't find better solution.
    // Does anyone have any suggestions?
    // =====================

    void
    ensure_capacity()
        {
        size_t const arr_size = _arr_iter - _arr_start;
        if (_capacity - arr_size  <  max_vb_size)
            {
            _capacity = _capacity*2 + max_vb_size;
            _arr_start = static_cast<char*>(realloc(_arr_start, _capacity));
            _arr_iter = _arr_start + arr_size;
            }
        }
    };
```

**main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "VBList.h"

int main()
    {
    using namespace std;
    // add to list
    VBList<unsigned long long> l;
    l.push_back(12);
    l.push_back(1223233);
    // iterate the list
    for (auto i: l)
        cout << i << endl;

    // write to file
    ofstream fout("file");
    ostreambuf_iterator<char> ofstr_iter (fout.rdbuf());
    VBOutputIterator<ostreambuf_iterator<char>, unsigned, false> out(ofstr_iter);
    out = 1;
    out = 333;
    out = 18;
    out.terminate();
    fout.flush();

    // read back from the file
    ifstream fin("file");
    VBInputIterator<istreambuf_iterator<char>, unsigned> in(fin.rdbuf());
    VBInputIterator<istreambuf_iterator<char>, unsigned> end;
    while (in != end)
        {
        cout << *in << endl;
        ++in;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

[https://github.com/jazzandrock/VBNumberList](https://github.com/jazzandrock/VBNumberList/tree/6f2a2d1eda4367adb6894795445e8ca5bab33406)

Comment: Any specific reason you're using `malloc` in a C++ project instead of `new`?

Comment: @yuri I really liked `realloc`, which copies the array on resize. The question is more like, why do I use raw arrays. I first tried to use `back_insert_iterator<vector<char>>`, but it doesn't allow writing a character and then overwriting it. Maybe in STL there is such iterator that allows that and also takes care of resizing?

Comment: Why do you pretend `VB` to each type name instead of using a namespace?

Comment: @yuri You should not even be using new in C++ really; make_shared and make_unique are the best in 90% of cases. Moreover even when using smart pointers there should be no raw new (this subtetly occurs when considering exceptions).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.  I'll start with more general things and then address your specific questions.

### Fix the bug

The `VBInputIterator` has a default second templated class `num_t=unsigned`.  That's not necessarily a problem, but its use in `VBList` is a bug:

```
typedef VBInputIterator<char*> iterator;
```

The problem is that if we're storing an `unsigned long long int` as in your example, the resulting iterator will only use `unsigned` which causes very large numbers such as `11122233344455566677ULL` to be displayed as 1967613269..

It should be this:

```
typedef VBInputIterator<char*, num_t> iterator;
```

I see little advantage (and plenty of disadvantage, as illustrated by this bug!) to providing a default class, so I'd advocate omitting it.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The `VBList` code uses `VBInputIterator` but doesn't `#include "VBInputIterator"`.

### Use `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>`

The difference between the two forms is that the former defines things within the `std::` namespace versus into the global namespace.  Language lawyers have lots of fun with this, but for daily use I'd recommend using `<cstdio>`.  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734230/math-interface-vs-cmath-in-c/8734292#8734292) for details.  However, see the next item.

### Use only required `#include`s

The code in `VBList.h` has `#include`s that are not needed. Specifically, neither `<stdio.h>` nor `<vector>` are required, so these may both be eliminated.  It's worth noting that `free` is actually defined in `<cstdlib>` rather than `<cstdio>`, so *if* you're going to use raw `malloc` and `free`, the code should `#include <cstdlib>`.  However, see the next item.

### Don't use leading underscores in names

Anything with a leading underscore in global space is a *reserved name* in C++ (and in C).  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for details.  Unless you're really sure about the language rules, I'd suggest avoiding leading underscore in names.  For similar reasons, I'd also avoid the `num_t` type name in the templates.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  I don't know that you've actually done that, but the use of raw `cout` and `endl` in your example program suggests that you may have.

### Rethink the interface

Consider the interface to the VBList.  It has constructors and a destructor, but the only public interfaces are `push_back(num_t n)` and `begin()` and `end()`.  This may be sufficient for some narrow purposes, but it doesn't, for example, allow the removal of numbers from the list, except by destroying the entire list.

### Prefer `new` and `delete` to `malloc` and `free`

Modern C++ tends to use `new` instead of `malloc`.  Doing so would eliminate the need for `<cstdlib>` and is more idiomatic C++.  In this case, I'd be inclined to use `std::vector` and avoid all four.  As a partially worked example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename unum>
class VBInputIterator {
public:
    typedef unum value_type;
    typedef unum& reference;
    typedef unum* pointer;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    explicit VBInputIterator(std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator ptr, std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator end) :
        ptr{ptr},
        end{end}
    {}

    VBInputIterator &operator++() { 
        for ( ; (ptr != end) && !(*ptr & 0x80) ; ++ptr) {
        }
        if (ptr != end) {
            ++ptr;
        }
        return *this; 
    }
    unum operator*() const { 
        unum val{};
        for (auto p{ptr} ; p != end; ++p) {
            uint8_t c = *p;
            val |= (c & 0x7f);
            if (c & 0x80)
                break;
            val <<= 7;
        }
        return val;
    }
    bool operator!=(const VBInputIterator<unum> &two) const {
        return ptr != two.ptr;
    }
private:
    std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator ptr;
    std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator end;
};

template <typename unum>
class VBList {
public:
    VBList() :
        vec{}
    {}
    void push_back(unum n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return;
        }
        std::vector<uint8_t> temp;
        temp.reserve(sizeof(n));
        temp.push_back((n & 0x7f) | 0x80);
        for (n >>=7 ; n; n >>= 7) {
            temp.push_back(n & 0x7f);
        }
        for (auto it{temp.rbegin()}; it != temp.rend(); ++it) {
            vec.push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    unum front() {
        return *(begin());
    }
    VBInputIterator<unum> begin() {
        return VBInputIterator<unum>{vec.begin(), vec.end()};
    }
    VBInputIterator<unum> end() {
        return VBInputIterator<unum>(vec.end(), vec.end()); 
    }
private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
};
```

Comment: Why naked pointers at all? This seems to go against 'robust and maintainable'.

Comment: Apart from being reserved, prepending things to distinguish member variables (like "<underscore>" or "m<underscore>") only generates more work for you imo as it takes longer for autocomplete to be helpful.

Comment: @David, Good point; it's why the rewritten version uses no pointers.